# What is the best way to handle Multi-instance Properties.Settings.Default.Save()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, configurationmanager

I have a C# Winforms application that uses app.config to save 3 simple settings.

- Last selected path as `string`
- Window state as `bool`
- Updated as `bool`

This is a multi-instance application and when a user has more then one instance open and closes the application group, they are met with

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to save settings: The configuration file has been changed by another program.

What is the best way to manage this?

I know I can catch the error and return out of application-exit method but this seems improper. It would seem to me that there should be a way to check if another instance is working in the file before calling `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` and then return out of the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch the exception and call [`Properties.Settings.Default.Reload()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.reload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then attempt to save again.

Comment: I take it there is no way to see if the file is in use to stop the exception during execution.

Comment: Well, of course you could.  But the file's not in use the problem is the contents have changed.  You can use [`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134265(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the location of the settings file.